How can I fix a 'socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed' when trying to use an SMTPHandler in Python 'logging'?
I am currently trying to log using the SMTPHandler class from Python's logging module. The logger is instantiated just fine, but fails when calling _socket.getaddrinfo even though it is being passed parameters which seem to work elsewhere. Below is the error message I get:
--- Logging error ---
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\logging\handlers.py", line 1075, in emit
    smtp = smtplib.SMTP(self.mailhost, port, timeout=self.timeout)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\smtplib.py", line 255, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\smtplib.py", line 341, in connect
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\smtplib.py", line 312, in _get_socket
    return socket.create_connection((host, port), timeout,
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\socket.py", line 827, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\socket.py", line 962, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed
Call stack:
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\idlelib\run.py", line 165, in main
    ret = method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\idlelib\run.py", line 579, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\test_log\test_log.py", line 34, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\test_log\test_log.py", line 28, in main
    log.critical('Testing email logging')
Message: 'Testing email logging'
Arguments: ()

I'm configuring the email handler and attempting to log as below.
Handler Config:
"emailhand": {
            "class": "logging.handlers.SMTPHandler",
            "level": "CRITICAL",
            "formatter": "a_formatter",
            "mailhost": "('send.smtp.com', 25)",
            "credentials": "('login@email.co.uk', 'password')",
            "fromaddr": "sender@email.co.uk",
            "toaddrs": "recipient@email.co.uk",
            "subject": "Test Log",
            "secure": "()",
            "timeout": 10.0
        }

Python Module:
import os
import json
import logging
import logging.config
import logging.handlers

def init_logging():

    logfile = r'C:\Users\User\Desktop\test_log\test_log.log'
    
    with open(r'C:\Users\User\Desktop\test_log\file-data\logging.json', 'r') as f:
        LOGGING_CONFIG = json.load(f)
    
    logging.config.dictConfig(LOGGING_CONFIG)


def main():
    init_logging()
    log = logging.getLogger('test_log')

    log.info('Some info from the main function')
    log.critical('Testing email logging')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

Currently I'm using TLS when connecting to the email server, but I've also tried with SSL and port 465 and this hasn't worked either. I've been able to successfully send emails using the smtp library with both TLS and SSL outside of this module by using smtplib.SMTP. I've attempted to alter the timeout value (anywhere from 1 to 10000) and this seems to have made no difference. I've also attempted to alter the emit function to use SMTP_SSL instead of SMTP and this didn't work. I've run socket.getaddrinfo with the same host and port as above and received the following (I've replaced the IP numbers with '#'):
[(<AddressFamily.AF_INET: 2>, 0, 0, '', ('###.##.###.##', 25)), (<AddressFamily.AF_INET: 2>, 0, 0, '', ('###.##.###.##', 25))]

As far as I can tell the above means that socket is working fine. What could be causing this issue?

Error 11001 is WSA_HOST_NOT_FOUND. Possibly related: Python "socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed" caused by socket.connect() and 11001 returned on all calls to getaddrinfo()

Solved the issue, it was a really basic mistake, I was passing tuples incorrectly through the json file. Instead of "('send.smtp.com', 25)" it should have been ["send.smtp.com", "25"]. The socket module was being passed '('send.smtp.com', 25)' as a string.
